# How to get the right manifest from project with multiple modules? [JAVA]

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, manifest, manifest.mf

I want to get to read from the Manifest of my Jar file to get the SVNVersion info from there and show it in the UI.
I work on a multi-module project that includes a client, a server running on tomcat, some modules of the client and its dependencies.

I wrote the code to access the current thread's manifest and get it's attributes.

```
Manifest mf = new Manifest();

    mf.read(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));

    Attributes atts = mf.getMainAttributes();
    System.out.println(atts.values());
    System.out.println("Version: " + atts.getClass());
    System.out.println("Revision: " + atts.get("SCM-Revision"));
    String scm = (String) atts.get("SCM-Revision");
    String revision = (String) atts.get("Revision-Number");
    return revision + scm;
}
```

The only thing is that it gets Null values returned because it get's the manifest of a dependency from the local repository that doesn't have the information i need inside of it.

Is there a solution to my problem? to specify a module from the project in a way so it know's to get IT's jar's Manifest and not the one from the dependency?
Thank you!

Comment: `getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")` will give you all the manifest files in the classpath

Comment: @MauricePerry, okay, and form all of those, how do i chose the one that would have that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I deleted my previous answer because it was buggy and unaccurate)

This is the procedure I used to have to get the proper manifest from any class in the classpath: It consists of getting it through a specific URL:

```
private static URL getManifestUrlForClass(Class<?> cl)
    throws MalformedURLException
{
    URL url=cl.getResource(cl.getSimpleName() + ".class");
    String s=url.toString();
    return new URL(s.substring(0, s.length() - (cl.getName() + ".class").length()) + "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

To use it from your code, just replace the first line:

```
mf.read(getManifestUrlForClass(MyClass.class).openStream());
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this on Monday.

Comment: Okay, I've tried this and it brought me closer to something that I need. It gives me the location of the current's module's class. From here i can navigate and get the Manifest. I just have to fiddle with it more. It's not the final answer but it helps a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, after trying it on the non-dev environment it works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You get a `null` because manifests are disabled in maven by default and what you get are values from the Jdk (jar containing the Thread-classfile). You either read

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/.../pom.properties")
```

or add the capability to create a manifest (depends on the modul packaging you have to pick the correct build-plugin for that).

Warning: `"/META-INF/.../pom.properties"` might have the **same** path in different Jars. Choose the Class first to determin what `pom.properties` you like to read.

Comment: I get null because the values that i am searching for inside the manifest do not exist, because i get the manifest file of a dependency instead of the client.

Comment: @SHPstr Thats what I said.